# Array of list of integers

Tags: java, arrays

I am attempting to construct an array where every "block" b has a list of every number x that make phi(x)=b (euler totient [A000010](http://oeis.org/A000010)). For example, arrray[10]=11,22 and array[4]=5,8,10,12. What I would've done normally is construct a 2d array, but this throws out an apparent stack overflow exception. Could you help me construct a more efficient stracture (heap-space wise).

Comment: How about you show us what you tried first?

Comment: You are likely looking for a array of (sorted) sets rather than an array of arrays.

Comment: My best attempt was using stacks, that is Stack<Integer>[] arr=new Stack<Integer>[n].

Comment: That's fine that you tried using a `Stack` but you really need to show your code and clearly identify where the exception is coming from. Nobody here is going to solve this problem for you, but we can certainly act as another set of eyes to point out potential improvements to your existing code.

Comment: What went wrong when you used `Stack<Integer>[]`?

Comment: Stack<Integer>[] arr=null; doesn't throw an exception, so I think the error has to do with the varriable being innitialized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you considered a list of lists?

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> listOflists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(11);
list.add(12);
listOflists.add(10,list);
```

Comment: You cannot use primitives for generics.

Comment: @bluesh34 I submitted an edit, just waiting for it to go through

Comment: @Rogue - you missed one!

Answer (score 1):

> What I would've done normally is construct a 2d array of size, but
>   this throws out an apparent stack overflow exception.

Well, yeah. your rows have a variable number of elements, so if you index something that the array hasn't allocated, you'll get an exception. Consider using `List`s or `Set`s for example:

```
List<List<Integer>> myOverlyComplexList = ...
```

Then you can have variable number sequences for each element.

Comment: That would produce an index out of bounds exception; the OP states a stack overflow exception, which implies that perhaps he is recursively generating the list somewhere and the problem is in the recursion.

Comment: Refactor to `myOvercomplicatedList` ;)

Comment: Jason C beat me to it. Given the examples the OP posted, this does sound like a reasonable answer to the question. But unless the OP mistyped or mis-read the exception, I'm not sure how they would get a stack overflow exception from using a 2d array.

Comment: OP actually said an "apparent stack overflow exception".  It's possible he/she ran out of heap space and misunderstood the error.

Comment: Still, if he's using static data structures to store elements of variable size, he might run into this issue later, so i'll leave it.

Comment: Well hopefully the OP posts code and an actual stack trace so we don't have to continue guessing.

Answer (score 1):

In java, the array's size is fixed. 
If the stuff you want to put in exceed the actual size, it will generate stack overflow(as our website).
I recommend you to use arraylist instead of array.
arraylist has dynamic size.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>()
```

Comment: That would generate an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, not a `StackOverflowError`.

Answer (score 1):

I think an array of sets or an array of lists will work better for you than a list of lists.  So forget about `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` and `List<List<Integer>>` and use either `Set<Integer>[]` or `List<Integer>[]`.

The reason is that once you calculate that `phi(x)` is `y`, you'll want to assign to entry `y` of the array.  But if it's a list, that means you suddenly have to add all the entries from the current `list.size()` up to `y`.  This is just a messy and unnecessary piece of code.

Please use an array, not a list; but feel free to put either lists or sets inside the array.

**Edit:**

You could initialise this with something like

```
int arraySize = 100;
List<?>[] list = new List<?>[arraySize];
```

Then when you discover that `phi(number) = phiNumber`, you might do something like

```
if (phiNumber < arraySize) {
    if (list[phiNumber] == null) {
        list[phiNumber] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }
    list[phiNumber].add(number);
}
else {
   // I don't know.  Print an error message?  Throw an exception?  You choose!
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But how exactly do I initiallize this variable? I attempted List<Integer>[] list=new List<Integer>[100] without success